# Searching for a certain parameter in a given String

Tags: javascript, html, full-text-search, jsoup

I'm having a major brain fart. I have a java application that adds items to carts, and I'm using JSOUP to parse the html document since it can't run any javascript scripts. So I extracted this out of the getElementsByTag().html(); function. And now I need to find the value 1038, but while keeping in mind the values is not always 1038. So I would need it to search attribute -> 92 -> options -> id = 1038.

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config({
"attributes": {
    "92": {
        "id": "92",
        "code": "color",
        "label": "Color",
        "options": [{
            "id": "1038",
            "label": "GREEN",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94035", "94036", "94037", "94038", "94039", "94040", "94041", "94042", "94043", "94044"]
        }]
    },
    "196": {
        "id": "196",
        "code": "size",
        "label": "Size",
        "options": [{
            "id": "189",
            "label": "8    ",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94041"]
        }, {
            "id": "188",
            "label": "8.5",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94042"]
        }, {
            "id": "187",
            "label": "9",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94043"]
        }, {
            "id": "186",
            "label": "9.5",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94044"]
        }, {
            "id": "185",
            "label": "10",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94035"]
        }, {
            "id": "184",
            "label": "10.5",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94036"]
        }, {
            "id": "183",
            "label": "11",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94037"]
        }, {
            "id": "182",
            "label": "11.5",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94038"]
        }, {
            "id": "181",
            "label": "12",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94039"]
        }, {
            "id": "179",
            "label": "13",
            "price": "0",
            "oldPrice": "0",
            "products": ["94040"]
        }]
    }
},
"template": "$#{price}",
"basePrice": "129.98",
"oldPrice": "180",
"productId": "94013",
"chooseText": "Choose an Option...",
"taxConfig": {
    "includeTax": false,
    "showIncludeTax": false,
    "showBothPrices": false,
    "defaultTax": 0,
    "currentTax": 0,
    "inclTaxTitle": "Incl. Tax"
}
```

});

I need to receive the value "1038", but it can't just be a search function for integer 1038, because that value can possibly change in my script.

Comment: You need to use a Json Parser to parse the text that is returned from html().

Comment: ^ Hmm, I'll give it a try right now. That was my first approach.